# How to call a step funtion from Node.js Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to call a step function from a Node.js lambda function. I tried the solution and updated implementations from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47689286/aws-call-a-step-function-from-lambda).

> The solution showing the error response but the updated code showing success response. But the updated code is not calling the step function.

**My Code:**

```js
console.log('Loading function');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Loading step functions');
    const stepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions({
    region: 'us-east-2'
});
console.log('Loading init');
module.exports.init = (event, context, callback) => {
console.log('Loading params');
const params = {
        stateMachineArn: 'ARN of My State Machine',
        // input: JSON.stringify({}), Optional if your statemachine requires an application/json input, make sure its stringified 
        name: 'TestExecution' // name can be anything you want, but it should change for every execution
    };

console.log('start step functions');
stepFunctions.startExecution(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 500,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'There was an error'
                })
            };
            callback(null, response);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            const response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: 'Step function worked'
                })
            };
            callback(null, response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    };
};
```

I have added the above code in a Lambda function and Deploy the codes. After that I have used the Test option of the lambda function. Is that the right way of executing a Lambda function? The test result is success, but when I check the state machine, there are no recent executions. Help me to find a solution for this, I am very new to step function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Standard Step function or Express Step function? Express Step functions doesn't have execution history, we can only see the cloudwatch logs if we enable them, but nothing in step function console

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Mine was Standard step function, when I run the lambda function, the execution was success, but nothing is happening on the step function. My step function returns a random integer number, but over here no output is on the lambda function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the things I did:

- created the lambda and added the permissions for the step function execution in the `lambda role`
- created the step function(just a hello world) of type `standard`. While creation I opted for `ALL Logs` which goes to `CloudWatch Log Group`. Even they are being shown in the `step function` console as below under the `Logging` tab.

Below is my code for calling the step function:

```js
var aws = require('aws-sdk')
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  var params = {
    stateMachineArn: 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:1234567890:stateMachine:Helloworld',
    input: JSON.stringify({})
  };
  var stepfunctions = new aws.StepFunctions()
  stepfunctions.startExecution(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'There was an error'
        })
    };
    callback(null, response);
    } else {
    console.log(data);
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Step function worked'
        })
    };
    callback(null, response);
    }
});
}
```

**Lambda Execution Logs**

[image]

**Step Function Execution Logs**

[image]

Comment: {
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"There was an error\"}"
}

Comment: I didn't understand the first 2 bulleted points, could you please elaborate that? Mostly the error is happening because of that.

Comment: @MatthewPans so the lambda where you are trying to call the step function must have an `IAM Role` attached. That `IAM Role` must have permissions to call the `step function` .  Ssecond `step function` must have logging configured with the necessary permissions as well  in the `IAM Role` it is using. I am assuming your lambda as well as step function exists in the same region `us-east-2`

Comment: Following is the error I am getting: HelloWorldLambda is not authorized to perform: states:StartExecution on resource: arn:aws:states:us-east-2:536963904807:stateMachine:HelloWorld

Comment: @MatthewPans yeah makes sense ... you have to amend the `lambda IAM role` and allow lambda role to call `step function`. For the time being attach the policy `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess` to the lambda iam role and test. Shjould work, later on you can customize the policy as per your needs.

Comment: in IAM Console after selecting the `lambda iam role` , under the `Permissions` tab there you can see the existing policies, click on `Attach Policies` . From the search bar search for `AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess` and then click on `Attach Policy`. Go back to your lambda and try executing it again.

Comment: Done adding policy for lambda IAM role. Is there any policy do we need to add for step function role? Currently I am getting this error: StartStepFunction is not authorized to perform: states:StartExecution on resource

Comment: @MatthewPans make sure your step function role have necessary permissions for  logging by [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951117/2246345).  Check if you have configured logging in the step function as well. [Logging using CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-logs.html). Seems like you need to amend permissions to step function iam role as well [State Machine-Level Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concept-create-iam-advanced.html#concept-create-iam-advanced-state)

Comment: @MatthewPans you dont have to specify any region if the everything is in the same region. [Defined runtime environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime).  The value of `AWS_REGION` var defaults to where the lambda is created.

Comment: It is working now, but when I execute it for the second time getting this error: ExecutionAlreadyExists: Execution Already Exists. Should we do something to stop the current execution?

Comment: @MatthewPans yes because you have name of the execution in your code `name: 'TestExecution'` remove this.

Comment: I have removed that line, but now the step function is executing 2 times when invoke it from lambda function

Comment: @MatthewPans are you using my code which I posted here or your own?

Comment: Same code you have posted. Removed the name part and changed the ARN with mine, no other changes.

Comment: I have added name and tested it again. At that time step function is executing only once. But in that case I can't call the step function for the second time.

Comment: @MatthewPans fault on my side, in the earlier code I shared I unknowingly left the call for step function execution twice. Removed and update the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67003106/how-to-invoke-a-lambda-function-using-the-request-id-and-update-the-running-stat

Answer (score 0):

It became easier with `aws-sdk` v3. Assuming that there's a step function created and the lambda has proper permissions set to trigger step function execution, the `handler` function can be:

```
import { SFNClient, StartExecutionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sfn';

export const handler = async (event) => {
  const client = new SFNClient({ region: '<some-region>' });
  const input = {
    stateMachineArn: '<arn-of-your-step-function>',
  };
  const command = new StartExecutionCommand(input);
  return await client.send(command);
};
```