# Give AWS Lambda an AWS Managed Policy with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-permissions

I have a Lambda function defined in CDK. I'm using this Lambda to invoke a State Machine and for that I would need to provide it some Policies. The way I tried was the following:

```js
const stepFunctionsPolicy = new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: ["states:*"],
      resources: ['*']
})

MachineLambda.addToRolePolicy(stepFunctionsPolicy) //Added the Policy to the Lambda's Role
```

This is a workaround, but ideally, I would like to provide AWS Managed Policies, instead of manually defining each policy, to this Lambda function (specifically the AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess)?

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-create-iam-role.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915029/how-to-call-a-step-funtion-from-node-js-lambda-function

Comment: @jspcal yea I did look over those but you definitely need a Policy attached to the Lambda function (my lambda function works totally fine and I can even call my Step Function), but the thing is I don't want to define multiple custom defined policies, I'd rather use AWS managed policies but assign it to Lambda with just CDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question specifically asks how to add the `AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess` managed policy to the Lambda's role.  This allows the Lambda to perform CRUD operations on all step functions:

```js
machineLambda.role?.addManagedPolicy(
   iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess")
);
```

Consider granting the Lambda narrow permissions instead, following the IAM [least privilege permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) security best practice:

```js
myStateMachine.grantExecution(machineLambda);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for the help! I will give my Lambda least permissions possible (by providing a grantExecution)